# How to specify timeout for tab completion in zsh?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

Zsh's completion feature is great except for this one. When I try to complete in a folder with lots of files/network folder, it takes a couple of minutes and prints this error.

```
example.com:~$ ls /path/to/some/bigFolder/[TAB]
zsh: do you wish to see all 620 possibilities (124 lines)?
```

Instead Is there a way to specify a timeout after which zsh should not try to auto-complete? I am not able to cancel its search too.

Comment: +1 Great question. I'd be curious about the same in bash.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> should cancel the completion. If it doesn't, then there's little chance anything else would.

Answer (score -1):

You can write a custom completer, implementing a timer/timeout, from the 
[zsh FAQ, section 4](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq04.html)
4.5: How do I get started with programmable completion?

Paraphrasing the FAQ

> The main resource is the [zshcompsys manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshcompsys) page.
>   ... or copy one of the very many existing functions.

Comment: so I should re-write whole completion system for a timeout feature? Has anyone done that already?

Comment: not rewrite, customize. And, iff you cannot find "one of the very many existing functions"

Comment: how many files do you have in one directory? Are you calling compinit in your .zshrc file?

Comment: This answer would be useful if you showed how to customize the completion system to have a timeout. I don't see a relevant `zstyle` setting in the `zshcompsys` man page. In fact, I doubt it is possible: I don't think you can interrupt zsh while it's expanding a glob, which is what is blocking here.